# iphone(objective-c) textview or label with linkable hastags and mentions and urls

Tags: iphone

Examlpe:
RT @iphonekkkhints: If you enjoy cross stitch then you can design your own iPhone case. Read how here: http://iphone-kkkkexperience.com/?p=1890 #kiran

I need to clickable on links,@iphonekkkhints,#kiran either in textview or Label

Is there any source code or apis please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try my Core text Hyperlink view.

https://github.com/jasarien/CoreTextHyperlinkView

It's a core text based view that allows for highlighting and tapping on links. The source includes a twitter specific subclass for highlighting and clicking @ mentions and # hash tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UITextView` using xib user interface and then open its properties and check the box on the detector of type link. And also uncheck the editable property of the `UITextView`.

or You can create Programmatically with this:

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 300, 200, 40)];
myTextView.text = @"http://iphone-kkkkexperience.com/?p=1890";
myTextView.editable=NO;
myTextView.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
[self.view addSubview:myTextView];
```

Comment: only hyper links is possible with that,but i need hash tags and mentions to be tapable.. i hope u got my point